# can't receive group message using xmpp

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, chatroom, groupchat

I can't receive group message on this method.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
   NSLog(@"Message received description === %@",[message description]);
}

-(void)sendGroupMessage:(NSString *)NameOfGroup :(NSString *)Msg
{
    [xmppRoom sendMessageWithBody:Msg];
    NSXMLElement *x = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:NameOfGroup xmlns:XMPPMUCNamespace];

    XMPPMessage *message = [XMPPMessage message];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NameOfGroup]];
    [message addChild:x];
    NSLog(@"x in Invite === %@",x);
    [xmppRoom sendMessage:message];

}

-(void)setUpRoom:(NSString *)ChatRoomJID
{

    NSString *Strng=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Abc@conference.localhost"];
    ChatRoomJID=Strng;
    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];

    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:ChatRoomJID];

    xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage jid:roomJID dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];
    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];


    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:self.UserID
                            history:nil
                           password:nil];

    [self performSelector:@selector(ConfigureNewRoom:) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];

}
```

First of all I create new group, send invitation and successfully accept it also for all invited users.
When I send message on that group, all person got message successfully, But if I will stop App and run again and login with xmpp and send message on group, message is not delivered to joined users.

When i have to log out and login again to xmpp server and send message on previously created group i got this error message

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="dharmraj123@conference.localhost" to="revoz1wwbzji1e1481005747@localhost/1824017799289652742921131" type="error"><body>1 Message</body><error code="406" type="modify"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></not-acceptable><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Only occupants are allowed to send messages to the conference</text></error></message>
```

Comment: What server u're using. Is it openfire? Seems like i'm also facing this issue in node-xmpp. When user is disconnected/logoff, cannot send message unless login with new jid. That jid is broken.

Comment: we are using ejabberd XMPP server.

Comment: got this error while send message 
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="dharmraj123@conference.localhost" to="revoz1wwbzji1e1481005747@localhost/1824017799289652742921131" type="error"><body>1 Message</body><error code="406" type="modify"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></not-acceptable><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Only occupants are allowed to send messages to the conference</text></error></message>